# How to validate person's address only if person doesn't belong to company?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

In my Rails 5 app I have the following setup:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :address, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

---

```
class Company < Client

  has_many :people

end
```

---

```
class Person < Client

  belongs_to :company

end
```

---

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true

  validates :city,        :presence   => true
  validates :postal_code, :presence   => true

end
```

A `person` *can* belong to a `company` but doesn't necessarily have to.

Now I want to validate a person's address only if that person doesn't belong to a company. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validations can take either an `if` or `unless` argument, which accept a method, proc or string to determine whether or not to run the validation.

In your case:

```
validates :address, presence: true, unless: :company
```

**Update according to comments**
The above only takes care of skipping the validation itself, but due to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` OP still saw errors when trying to persist a missing address. This solved it:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, reject_if: :company_id
```

Comment: Thanks. None of the provided solutions works. I guess that's because of the validations inside my `Address` model? I added them above. If only I could *disable* them on certain conditions... (e.g. when a person belongs to a company).

Comment: The above should work for your original question, i.e. skipping the presence validation. If your code then still goes on and tries to persist an address it can't be sure is actually there you will of course fail the validations on the `Address` side.

Comment: So maybe what you actually want is `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, reject_if: :company` on the `Person` class. This way you wouldn't try to persist an address if a person belongs to a company, instead of just skipping the validation.

Comment: Your last comment solved it! I added two different `accepts_nested_attributes_for` statements, one to the `Company` class and one to the `Person` class. In the `Person` class I've got `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, reject_if: :company_id` and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There might be other approaches as well, but based on my experience, something like this should work.

```
validates :address, :presence => true, if: -> {!company}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use `unless` instead of `if` and `!`. Also since it's a simple method call, you can just specify it via a symbol, i.e. `unless: :company`.

Comment: Thanks. I can't get this to work unfortunately. I added my `Address` code above. Some address fields are always required. I wonder how to circumvent that.

Answer (score 2):

Nabin's answer is good but wanted to show another way.

```
validate :address_is_present_if_no_company

def address_is_present_if_no_company
  return if !company_id || address
  errors.add(:address, "is blank")
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realized that my initial question was a little misleading as I've got validation methods in my `Address` class as well. (I added them above.) Apart from that, your code would have probably been perfect.